# What is the name of this part on a 2003 Mazda Protege5?

Tags: lights, parts, part-identification

I'm coming up empty-handed on a Google search so maybe I'm not searching with the right vocabulary.

I have 2 LEDs out and I'm not sure if the single bulb can be replaced or if it's one single part for all lights.  I feel like I found a site a couple of weeks ago, but didn't bookmark it and can't find it again.   What is this part officially called? Are there part number(s)?

```
                               What is this?
```

[image: Need part identification]

Is this the sort of replacement something a non-mechanic can attempt or should it be left to the pros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a Center High Mount Stop Lamp (CHMSL) or sometimes a Center High Mount Brake Lamp (CHMBL).

If you can't find a Web site with part numbers, you could go to the parts counter at a Mazda dealer and ask them to look up the part number(s). They can tell you whether it's all one piece or not.

I don't know how to take the light apart in your car. Your owner's manual is probably no help here. You might be able to find disassembly instructions in a repair manual.

Answer (score 3):

It's commonly called a third brake light, although the [William Cline](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/785/what-is-the-name-of-this-part-on-a-2003-mazda-protege5/786#786) listed the more technical terms for them.

You can find several used ones at [car-part.com](http://www.car-part.com/) prices range from $20 - $50

You will need to replace the assembly you cannot replace just one of the bulbs.